# Why is it needed to nest properties in TS when passing an entire object as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So, let's see the following example, which will throw an error:

```
interface PersonData {
    name: string
    age: number
    country: string
}

function PersonName({data}: PersonData) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{data.name}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The TS error is the following:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'PersonData'.
```

And if we nest the properties in the interface then it works. Like so:

```
interface PersonData {
  data{
    name: string
    age: number
    country: string
  }
}

function PersonName({data}: PersonData) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{data.name}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But why? I don't understand the logic.

Comment: `{data}` is destructuring the `data` key out of the object, have you tried just using `function PersonName(data: PersonData) {`?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason in my React App it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this, you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `data` property from `PersonData`, which doesn't exist:

```
function PersonName({data}: PersonData) {
```

This is the same as saying:

```
function PersonName(props: PersonData) {
   const data = props.data;
```

The reason the update to your interface works is you are explicitly adding a `data` key to the interface.

Two ways you can fix this, first is to not destructure (notice that `data` in the function definition is no longer in curly braces):

```
function PersonName(data: PersonData) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{data.name}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The other is to destructure the keys that *do* exist, like:

```
function PersonName({ name }: PersonData) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
interface PersonData {
    name: string
    age: number
    country: string
}

function PersonName({data}: PersonData) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{data.name}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
interface PersonData {
    name: string
    age: number
    country: string
}

function PersonName(props: PersonData) {
  const data = props.data;
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{data.name}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
interface IProps {
  data: PersonData
}

function PersonName({data}:IProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{data.name}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```